# Google Places Web API incorrectly throwing error and breaking maps on nearbySearch

Tags: web-services, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm attempting to pull some places from the Places Web API in order to draw some markers on a map. It seems like it is incorrectly throwing an error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify location.
>
> in places_impl.js:35
> ```

My code follows:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.nearbySearch({
    bounds: bounds,
    type: ['natural_feature']
}, callback);
```

and it should work as per the documentation:

> This method takes a request with the following fields:
>
> Either of:
>   ***bounds***, which must be a google.maps.LatLngBounds object defining the rectangular search area; ***or***
>
> ***a location and a radius***; the former takes a google.maps.LatLng object, and the latter takes a simple integer, representing the circle's radius in meters. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that when rankBy is set to DISTANCE, you must specify a location but you cannot specify a radius or bounds.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `bounds` is not valid when you are calling the service.

The map is initialized asynchronously, the bounds isn't available until the `bounds_changed` event fires for the first time.

Wait until the 'bounds_changed' event fires on the map before using `map.getBounds()`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch({
    bounds: bounds,
    type: ['natural_feature']
  }, callback);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2qq02shw/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.nearbySearch({
      bounds: bounds,
      type: ['natural_feature']
    }, callback);
  });

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Waiting for bounds_changed event to fire did the job.
In the documentation however:

_If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the result is null or undefined._

In my case, I was initializing the map and center and zoom were being set. So still odd. Anyways, cheers.

Comment: The map is initialized asynchronously, the bounds isn't available until the `bounds_changed` event fires for the first time.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help